# Evaluate the integral by finding the Laurent series

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, laurent-series

By finding the appropriate Laurent series, evaluate the integral where C is the unit circle, traversed once in the positive direction.

$$\int_{C} (z^3 - e^\frac{1}{z}) \cos \left(\frac{1}{z}\right)dz$$

Unsure what the Laurent Series is for the complex function.

Comment: Without the 'Laurent Series', you can make the change $z \to 1/z$.

Answer (score 1):

The integrand $f(z):=(z^3 - e^{1/z}) \cos (1/z)$ has "only" an essential singularity at $z=0$ (which is inside the unit circle). Hence, by the  [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), 
$$\int_{|z|=1} f(z)dz=2\pi i\,\mbox{Res}(f,0)=2\pi i a_{-1}$$
where $a_{-1}$ is the coefficient of $1/z$ in the [Laurent expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) of $f$ in a neighbourhood of $z=0$.

In order to find $a_{-1}$ recall that
$$e^{1/z}=1+\frac{1}{z}+O(1/z^2)\quad \mbox{and}\quad \cos(1/z)=1-\frac{1}{2z^2}+\frac{1}{24z^4}+O(1/z^6).$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Use the expansions that I gave you and compute the product $(z^3 - e^{1/z}) \cos (1/z)$. What do you get?

Comment: You have not considered all the terms that I have written down...

Comment: So expanding the brackets, the only 2 terms with 1/z are (1/24z - 1/z), is this correct

Comment: hence the coefficient of 1/z is just -23/24 ?

Comment: Are you unsure about that?

Comment: Yes, $1/24-1=-23/24$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Besides any 'Laurent Expansion', you can make the change $\ds{z \mapsto 1/z}$. That yields an integrand which has a pole of order *five* at
>   $\ds{z = 0}$.

Namely,
\begin{align}
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\pars{z^{3} - \expo{1/z}}\cos\pars{1 \over z}\dd z &
\,\,\,\stackrel{z\ \mapsto\ 1/z}{=}\,\,\,
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
{\pars{1 - z^{3}\expo{z}}\cos\pars{z} \over z^{5}}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
2\pi\ic\,{1 \over 4!}\ \underbrace{\lim_{z \to 0}
\totald[4]{\bracks{\pars{1 - z^{3}\expo{z}}\cos\pars{z}}}{z}}_{\ds{=\ -23}}\ =\
\bbx{-\,{23 \over 12}\,\pi\ic}
\end{align}

> Otherwise, you can do the following approach:

\begin{align}
&{\pars{1 - z^{3}\expo{z}}\cos\pars{z} \over z^{5}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ z\ \to\ 0}{\sim}\,\,\,
{\pars{1 - z^{3} - z^{4}}\pars{1 - z^{2}/2 + z^{4}/24} \over z^{5}}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ z\ \to\ 0}{\sim}\,\,\,&\
{1 \over 2} + {1 \over z^{5}} - {1 \over 2}{1 \over z^{3}} - {1 \over z^{2}} +
\pars{\color{red}{-\,{23 \over 24}}}{1 \over z}
\end{align}